# Turning a List of Transactions into Hourly/Daily Prices in R

Tags: r, transformation, xts, quantmod

I've downloaded a list of every Bitcoin transaction on a large exchange since 2013. What I have now looks like this:

```
                  Time Price    Volume
1  2013-03-31 22:07:49  93.3 80.628518
2  2013-03-31 22:08:13 100.0 20.000000
3  2013-03-31 22:08:14 100.0  1.000000
4  2013-03-31 22:08:16 100.0  5.900000
5  2013-03-31 22:08:19 100.0 29.833879
6  2013-03-31 22:08:21 100.0 20.000000
7  2013-03-31 22:08:25 100.0 10.000000
8  2013-03-31 22:08:29 100.0  1.000000 
9  2013-03-31 22:08:31 100.0  5.566121
10 2013-03-31 22:09:27  93.3 33.676862
```

I'm trying to work with the data in **R**, but my computer isn't powerful enough to handle processing it when I run `getSymbols(BTC_XTS)`. I'm trying to convert it to a format like the following (price action over a day):

```
   Date       Open  High  Low   Close  Volume       Adj.Close
1  2014-04-11 32.64 33.48 32.15 32.87 28040700     32.87
2  2014-04-10 34.88 34.98 33.09 33.40 33970700     33.40
3  2014-04-09 34.19 35.00 33.95 34.87 21597500     34.87
4  2014-04-08 33.10 34.43 33.02 33.83 35440300     33.83
5  2014-04-07 34.11 34.37 32.53 33.07 47770200     33.07
6  2014-04-04 36.01 36.05 33.83 34.26 41049900     34.26
7  2014-04-03 36.66 36.79 35.51 35.76 16792000     35.76
8  2014-04-02 36.68 36.86 36.56 36.64 14522800     36.64
9  2014-04-01 36.16 36.86 36.15 36.49 15734000     36.49
10 2014-03-31 36.46 36.58 35.73 35.90 15153200     35.90
```

I'm new to **R**, and any response would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you could mean when you say your "computer isn't powerful enough to handle processing it when [you] run `getSymbols(BTC_XTS)`". `getSymbols` retrieves data... why do you need to retrieve data you already have?

Also, you have no adjusted close data, so it's not possible to have an `Adj.Close` column in the output.

You can get what you want by coercing your input data to xts and calling `to.daily` on it. For example:

```
require(xts)
Data <- structure(list(Time = c("2013-03-31 22:07:49", "2013-03-31 22:08:13", 
"2013-03-31 22:08:14", "2013-03-31 22:08:16", "2013-03-31 22:08:19", 
"2013-03-31 22:08:21", "2013-03-31 22:08:25", "2013-03-31 22:08:29", 
"2013-03-31 22:08:31", "2013-03-31 22:09:27"), Price = c(93.3, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 93.3), Volume = c(80.628518, 
20, 1, 5.9, 29.833879, 20, 10, 1, 5.566121, 33.676862)), .Names = c("Time", 
"Price", "Volume"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
x <- xts(Data[,-1], as.POSIXct(Data[,1]))
d <- to.daily(x, name="BTC")
```